Dynamic job dependency in gitlab-ci.yml to depend on a job variant in matrix
I have a build job that builds multiple variants in parallel jobs:
build-firmware:
  stage: build
  script: |
    echo "Building ${BOARD}_${BUILD_TYPE}"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - firmware_${BOARD}_${BUILD_TYPE}.bin
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - BOARD: [board1, board2]
        BUILD_TYPE: [debug, release]

This creates 4 jobs as board1_debug, board1_release, board2_debug, board2_release.
I also have a release job which also has the same matrix and is supposed to release the artifacts from corresponding build job. Since the build takes long time, I don't always wait for all the builds to be completed so I just cancel the ones that I don't need. In this case, I'd need a dependency/needs setting in my release job to depend on the corresponding build variant, instead of all the build jobs. Otherwise it just gets skipped because there are cancelled jobs.
I'm looking for a syntax like this but apparently it's not possible to have placeholders in the needs directive in gitlab:
release-firmware:
  stage: release
  needs:
    - job: build-firmware:${BOARD}:${BOOT_TYPE}:${BUILD_TYPE}
  script: |
      echo "Releasing firmware for ${BOARD} ${BOOT_TYPE} ${BUILD_TYPE}"
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - BOARD: [board1, board2]
        BUILD_TYPE: [debug, release]


You may need to use needs:parallel:matrix. I don't know if you can inject variables in it though.

I agree with @GaëlJ: Take a look at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#needsparallelmatrix

I can use needs:parallel:matrix but it doesn't replace the placeholders there.

It is not possible with parallel:matrix but you can use inputs. It works like functions. Use spec:inputs to define parameters that can be populated in reusable CI/CD configuration files when added to a pipeline.
First in another file (build-firmware.yml), we define the reusable code (Note the --- that should be between the spec and the functions:
# build-firmware.yml
spec:
  inputs:
    BOARD:
      description: "The Board."
      options: ['board1', 'board2']
    BUILD_TYPE:
      description: "The build type."
      options: ['debug', 'release']
---

"build-firmware-$[[ inputs.BOARD ]]-$[[ inputs.BUILD_TYPE ]]":
  stage: $[[ inputs.BUILD_TYPE ]]
  script: |
    echo "Building $[[ inputs.BOARD ]]_$[[ inputs.BUILD_TYPE ]]"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - firmware_$[[ inputs.BOARD ]]_$[[ inputs.BUILD_TYPE ]].bin

"release-firmware-$[[ inputs.BOARD ]]-$[[ inputs.BUILD_TYPE ]]":
  stage: $[[ inputs.BUILD_TYPE ]]
  script: |
    echo "Releasing firmware for $[[ inputs.BOARD ]] $[[ inputs.BUILD_TYPE ]]"
  needs:
    - job: build-firmware-$[[ inputs.BOARD ]]-$[[ inputs.BUILD_TYPE ]]

Then in your .gitlab-ci.yml, we include them with the values:
# .gitlab-ci.yml

stages:
  - debug
  - release

include:
  - local: 'build-firmware.yml'
    inputs:
      BOARD: board1
      BUILD_TYPE: debug
  - local: 'build-firmware.yml'
    inputs:
      BOARD: board2
      BUILD_TYPE: release


Thanks for the answer. Though this is not exactly solving my problem as I'd anyway need to define as much variants for each input. I actually have a lot more variants, board types and different variables so I just wanted to define a matrix in dependencies as well.
Similar to what you suggested, I'm using templates as a workaround. And then expanding the template for each variant by specifying the needs:job:parallel:matrix
